# setting a default locale

Tags: locale, symfony, symfony-routing

I'm trying to implement the locale in the routes.
I can get it to work like `host/en/page` & `host/fr/page` with this snippet:

```
#routing.yml

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: nl|en
```

But my goal is to be able to use `host/page` where the locale would not be in the url, but is set as a default locale.

How do I do this? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

**Edit, trying out the JMSI18nRoutingBundle**

additions:

```
# config.yml

jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: nl
    locales: [nl, en]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

.

```
# security.yml > firewalls section

form_login:
        login_path: _login
        check_path: _login
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
    logout:
        path:   _logout
        target: /
```

.

```
# routing.yml

_logout:
    path: /logout
    options: { i18n: false }
_login:
    path: /login
    options: { i18n: false }
```

Routes are prefixed as they should, but I'm unable to use my **login** and **logout** routes.

Comment: There is simple bundle for that https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Comment: I did just take a look at it but it's only for symfony 2. I'm using symfony 3. I can't even install it with composer.

Comment: I'm on Symfony 3.0.6 and use this bundle every time. Add to composer: `"jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "^2.0",`

Comment: hmmn very well, I'll try it again. Will keep you posted.

Comment: ah yes, seems I used the wrong version. This seems to work, put is as an answer and I'd happily accept it, thank you!

Comment: It does break my login page & route, how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you setup the bundle? Add config and everything should work.

Comment: yes yes it works, but now it expects the locales to prefix my login and logout routes

Comment: Check my answer for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle bundle.

In `app/config.yml` setup the bundle for default locale.

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: nl
    locales: [nl, en]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Comment: You should also remove requirements and prefix added before to routes. It cannot broke routes if default language is set, the routes stay as is.

Comment: I'm editing my post to better reflect what I've tried so far

Comment: And you removed all the stuff from routing that you added before? For me the bundle always working perfect, I do nothing with routing, if I not translate routes in `translations/routes.en.yml` or any other language, all routes stay at is before.

Comment: nope, all my routes are basic routes, the others are shown above.